# Need Windows GUI for Python .exe script

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, button, exe

I wrote a py .exe script and need to create a GUI for it with a file path input field, a 'cancel' and 'ok' buttons. How can I accomplish it best? Do I need to bind it with any C libraries? I know I could easily create a web based interface but I do not want a web app, I need a .exe app.
Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a simple GUI, Python comes with a built in library: [TkInter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter). It's somewhat ugly, but it might be fine for your purposes - requires nothing 3rd party, so no additional installations. If you want something more full featured, I'd suggest [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/)

Comment: Hi, I think that you're right, Tkinter will do. Do you know the proper syntax to import tkSimpleDialog.askstring and collect the file path in a variable? Tks.

Comment: You most likely want an entry widget for collecting a file path - see http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm for how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

[wxPython](http://wxpython.org/) is the best thing I can think of.

Comment: Tks, but I think that Tkinter will do. I'm just trying to find the right syntax for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at easydialogs for window http://www.averdevelopment.com/python/EasyDialogs.html